# Hacking RJS behaviour in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I have a old rails 2.x project that I have converted mostly over to rails 5.

One issue is some of my actions used RJS, so it looked like:

```
if request.xhr?
  render :action => 'new_user' and return
end
```

The new_user.js.rjs looks something like:

```
page.call "User.create", render(:partial => 'new_user'), {:userId => @user.id}
```

Looking at the response in chrome I can see it is just returning:

```
User.create('<tr><td>....</td></tr>', {"userId" : 123});
```

I only have to support the page.call type RJS call, what would be a easy "hack" to get this to work in rails 5?

I don't want to modify all of my javascript code, I just need to basically have a javascript block that I pass the JS code to in my view pages right?

Comment: So you mean you cant use rjs in rails 5?

Comment: @AkiraSuzuki Yeah I believe it was taken out in rails 3.x

Comment: You can still respond to js and have it update your view in rails 5.2 `new_user.js.erb`
see: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Comment: @RGB but RJS is deprecated?

Comment: its not RJS anymore, but the 'behaviour' is still available. see the Edge guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up returning a JSON response to my view pages like this:

```
some_partial_html = render_to_string(:partial => 'something')

response = {
  "html": some_partial_html,
  "a" : 1
}.to_json
render json: response
```

And then in my view I used the json response values as arguements to the javascript object that performs the functionality I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to render a response as a string:

```
if request.xhr?
  render render_to_string partial: 'new_user',
    locals: { userId: @user.id },
    layout: false
end
```

Or try to use format handler instead:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.rjs do
     render render_to_string partial: 'new_user',
       locals: { userId: @user.id },
       layout: false
   end
end
```